# How do I create an alternative subdomain for my typepad profile with GoDaddy?

Tags: cname-record, godaddy

I'm trying to point a sub-domain to my typepad profile, but it returns a blank page?
info.9am-5pm.com --> myname****.typepad.com

Also, I've added a new CNAME for "bbs." try to make the following redirection, which returns a 403 Forbidden.
bbs.9am-5pm.com --> 9am-5pm.5d6d.com

Is there something wrong at the CNAME part? or if there's anything I can do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination sites, in this case typepad.com and 5d6d.com, need to know that they host those websites, info.9am-5pm.com and bbs.9am-5pm.com. Most likely you need to buy some service from these providers. For example, for Typepad you need to have a "Plus or Pro subscription" (http://www.sixapart.com/typepad/news/2004/03/domain_mapping_3.html )